# Dynamic blog working on local but on server blog page show show http error 500

Tags: php, .htaccess, webserver, hosting

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

RewriteRule ^c-(.*)$ catpost.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^a-(.*)-(.*)$ archives.php?month=$1&year=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ viewpost.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

check this URL - http://emkconsultant.com/blog/
I think the issue in .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe from your apache server config! Check error log of apache from:

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Comment: my hosting provider use Lite speed server